# URL of HTML5 video in webview - not full screen

Tags: android, webview, android-browser

I am able to get the url of the html5 video in a webview when the video goes full screen through the showCustomView event, is there a way for me to do that when the videos do not go full screen? Essentially I need to be able to get an instance of the focused child of the webview.

Thanks.